# Ubuntu 14.04 Hangs While Screen is Off

Tags: 14.04, freeze, overheating, screensaver, crash

I have an Asus G73JW laptop with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

While I'm using the laptop, it works quite well - but if I leave the laptop unattended for a while, I come back it will have a black screen and won't come back.  I've also noticed the laptop is really hot.  It seems like the fans go down to minimum, and maybe that causes the laptop to overheat and freeze?  I have another laptop that seems to have the same symptoms - a Dell Inspiron 1445 - however I don't find it hot.

I can't tell whether it's that the computer hangs while the fans just by chance are running too low, and it gets hot because of it, or if it hangs because it gets hot.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to troubleshoot?  I did not have these issues on 13.10!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it might be related to the video card driver.  Perhaps you should specify whether the card, and whether you are using the open driver, or the closed driver.  Also, perhaps try switching one to the other to see if there is a difference.

Comment: It's an GTX460m in this machine.  It was originally on the 331.38 nVidia drivers - I just switched it to the legacy 304.117 drivers and we'll see how it holds up.  Still find it weird though since it didn't hang before...

Comment: Well, when you do an upgrade, you often get a newer version of drivers and Linux itself. I had an old Dell laptop where the display  would basically no longer work at all after one update, on all distros I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Marty suggested, I switched from the latest and greatest 331.38 nVidia drivers to the legacy 304.117 drivers and it seems to have fixed the crashing! :)